# Cannot get webkit kiosk to load on boot

Tags: ubuntu, webkit, frame, kiosk

I followed some online tutorial instructions to get a web kiosk loaded on ubuntu. It works great but I am having a hard time getting the kiosk to fully load on boot. I'm sure I am just missing a simple command.

These are the commands I followed:

```
Install frame with snap
sudo snap install ubuntu-frame

Install a web kiosk for frame
sudo snap install wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk

Start frame by default
sudo snap set ubuntu-frame daemon=true

Start the kiosk by default also
sudo snap set wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk daemon=true

Connect the kiosk to frame
sudo snap connect wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk:wayland

Start it all up
sudo snap start wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk
```

If I follow those commands it will load the kiosk. But after a reboot it will not and the system boots to a grey screen (I think thats the frame app), if I ssh into the kiosk machine and issue the command `sudo snap connect wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk:wayland` then it loads up immediately. I thought enabling the daemons would make it start on boot?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there is probably a better way but I could not find it. I just added a crontab entry to run the command at boot. Works.

```
@reboot sudo snap connect wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk:wayland
```

Answer (score 0):

In combination with frame-it, this was needed:

```
sudo snap connect ubuntu-frame:login-session-control
```

Maybe this helps: https://mir-server.io/docs/how-to-smooth-boot-with-ubuntu-frame